# gitkraken error: Invalid remote name "origin": invalid remote name: "path project"\origin

Tags: gitkraken

I was using gitkraken normally, and today I started having this problem in gitkraken:

[Error gitkraken](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FOSAN.jpg)

[log description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cfb9B.jpg)

Please, could someone help me? maybe how to force gitkraken to create this folder in its default???

Please, could someone help me? maybe how to force gitkraken to create this folder in its default???